# Email to Case setup using Microsoft exchange and office 365

Tags: service-cloud-console, email2case, servicecloud, service

Can anyone please guide me or provide some links that helps to setup an email to case.

I know how to configure email to case and working perfectly using gmail. I have installed email to case agent also but not getting any idea.Do i need to some configuration setting by going back to ms exchange. or simply verfying email address

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your exchange administrator to setup a rule in exchange server(s) to forward all emails to Salesforce. I believe you have a generic email address where users can email. Refer On-Demand Email-to-Case on https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006097&language=en_US

Comment: So,after that do i need to verify routing address?

Comment: Yes, go to Customize ->  Cases -> Email-to_case and create a new routing address. Provide the "Email Services Address" to exchange admin to setup routing.

Comment: Thanks! Is that setting up like using gmail account to generate email to Case?

Comment: And one more thing there is no need of using email to case agent?

Comment: Yes no need for the agent.